# Is it possible to skip 'x' results in Cassandra SELECT statement? | PAGINATION

Tags: cassandra

I want to implement a simple pagination for my app which uses latest Cassandra. I am looking for 3 days, but can't find anything useful (neither in DS docs, nor using Google).

Long story short - is it possible to skip 'x' results while making SELECT statement? I don't want to do that *after* SELECT returns me all results, I want a SELECT statement to return *only defined by **skip** and **size*** results.

Is it possible in Cassandra? I saw this:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html#reference_ds_d35_v2q_xj__paging-through-unordered-results

and read about iterator, but it doesn't look like the thing I am looking for (iterator seems to iterate over results which are already *taken* from database; above link looks like some kind of *intable* pagination (it is some kind of workaround)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in "skip" functionality, only the limit that allows you to restrict the number of rows returned back.   But Cassandra supports so-called paging state that will allow you to show results starting with the "last fetched position" (see [Cassandra's native protocol specification](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/doc/native_protocol_v4.spec) for technical details (section 8)).  But that will allow you to implement only "forward paging", for backward paging you need to remember where you already stopped (just cache paging states, or "remember" the full primary key)

Some of drivers (or all, don't remember out of head) are exposing that paging state via API, so you can put it into cookie, or store somewhere else (for example, see [doc for Java driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.9/manual/core/paging/)).  Java driver, also [provides OffsetPager class](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.9/manual/core/paging/#offset-queries), that emulates paging and random access to the data, but under the hood it's just skipping not necessary results, so be aware of performance implications.